# Cache data outside of Application

Tags: c#, .net, caching

Im trying to cache data that i get from a SQL Service, i tried using the Memory Cache Class from System.Runtime.Caching but it seems like the Cache is being emptied whenever i exit the Application.

So my Question is, is there a way to Cache my Data so i can get it even if my Application restarted?

Im Working with a Service from Biztalk so the Application gets started whenever its needed, but the SQL polling takes too long.

Here is the Code im testing with:

```
const string KEY = "key";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        Cache(cache);
        Get(cache);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Get(MemoryCache cache)
    {
        string result = cache.Get(KEY) as string;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private static void Cache(MemoryCache cache)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10);
        bool res = cache.Add(KEY, "This was Cached", policy);
        if (res)
            Console.WriteLine("Added Succesfully");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Adding Failed");
    }
```

Comment: MemoryCache only stores data in memory. You'll need a FileCache or DatabaseCache but none of those exist AFAIK in the framework.

Comment: you can try Redis (https://redis.io/) for caching

Answer (score 2):

> So my Question is, is there a way to Cache my Data so i can get it even if my Application restarted?

Yes. If you use [`CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempriority(v=vs.110).aspx), the cache will survive even if the application restarts.

```
ObjectCache cache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default;
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy
{
    Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10);
};

cache.Add(item, policy);
```

> **MSDN NOTE:** Adding an entry to the cache with a priority level of NotRemovable has the potential to overflow the cache with entries that can never be removed. Cache implementations should only set the NotRemovable priority for a cache entry if they provide ways to evict such entries from the cache and to manage the number of cache entries.

Comment: If "app restart" means new process / app domain, there is no way the MemoryCache still has your previously cached items, no matter how hard you cache them ;)

Comment: This works in ASP.NET-based applications. Of course, if you are talking about a thick client, restarting the application is a different story and all memory allocated will be lost, including the cache. But I am using this in ASP.NET and I can restart the application without losing cached data.